# Unknown column error in where clause, using MySQL and Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, connection, database-connection

Following is my code line :

```
ResultSet rs3 = stmt6.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM ShopSystem.Order where s_id="+s_id+" AND status="+Pending);
```

I am getting the following error :

```
Unknown column 'Pending' in 'where clause'
```

What could be the reason... I cant get through it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No doubt, `status` is a string, so it needs to be compared to a string.  Use delimiters:

```
SELECT * FROM ShopSystem.Order where s_id="+s_id+" AND status='"+Pending+"'"
```

Or better yet, learn how to write code that uses parameter substitution for putting parameter values into SQL strings.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to

```
AND status = '" + Pending + "'"
```

You need to put the string in quotes. Otherwise the DB thinks you mean a column name.

But actually you should use *Prepared Statements*. Then you don't need to patch the queries together like this and you don't worry about parameters and escaping them...

Answer (score 0):

Don't make concatenation ! Use prepared statements

```
PreparedStatement stm = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM ShopSystem.Order where s_id = ? AND status = ?");
stm.setInt(1, s_id);
stm.setString(2, Pending.name());
ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use the PreparedStatement in this case

```
// use the ? for the 2 entries values
    String selectSQL = new String("SELECT * FROM ShopSystem.Order where s_id=? AND status=?")
    preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(selectSQL);
// in order you must incialise them here                
                 preparedStatement.setString(1, "s_id");
                preparedStatement.setString(2, "Pending");
//execute your resultset    `enter code here`
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```